# Chart in Visual Studio Blend 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, visual-studio-2015

I am working in Visual Studio Blend 2015 and I need to add a line chart in my WPF application. The problem is that I don´t found the 'Chart' tool, as the existing in Visual Studio. I´ve try to add new references but this tool doesn´t appear. Anyone knows about that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Tool? Do you mean the WinForms charting control? Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll (not sure about DLL name...should be)

Comment: You can find many nuget packages for wpf, for example `OxyPlot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have got the solution.
I have created a line chart with two lines as it is showed in the picture.

[image]

'using OxyPlot'
The code is:

```css
            
            OxyPlot.PlotModel PM = new OxyPlot.PlotModel();
            PM.LegendTitle = "Legend";

            PM.IsLegendVisible = false;
            PM.PlotAreaBorderColor = OxyColor.FromRgb(203, 203, 203);

            var valueAxisX = new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis() { MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None, MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None, Title = "Value" };
            valueAxisX.Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Bottom;
            valueAxisX.StartPosition = 0;
            valueAxisX.Title = "Weeks";
            valueAxisX.TitleColor = OxyColor.FromRgb(66, 66, 66);
            PM.Axes.Add(valueAxisX);
            var valueAxisY = new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis() { MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None, MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None, Title = "Value" };
            valueAxisY.Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Left;
            valueAxisY.StartPosition = 0;
            valueAxisY.Title = "Requirements";
            valueAxisY.TitleColor = OxyColor.FromRgb(66, 66, 66);
            PM.Axes.Add(valueAxisY);

            var lineSerie = new OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries();
            lineSerie.StrokeThickness = 3;
            lineSerie.Color = OxyColor.FromRgb(59, 127, 196);
            lineSerie.MarkerType = MarkerType.None;
            lineSerie.Title = "Requirements";
            lineSerie.Smooth = false;

            lineSerie.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 25));
            lineSerie.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 40));
            lineSerie.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 40));
            lineSerie.Points.Add(new DataPoint(4, 50));
            lineSerie.Points.Add(new DataPoint(5, 100));

            var lineSerie2 = new OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries();
            lineSerie2.StrokeThickness = 2;
            lineSerie2.Color = OxyColor.FromRgb(141, 190, 239);
            lineSerie2.MarkerType = MarkerType.None;
            lineSerie2.Title = "Requirements_traced";
            lineSerie2.Smooth = false;

            lineSerie2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(1, 20));
            lineSerie2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(2, 30));
            lineSerie2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(3, 40));
            lineSerie2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(4, 45));
            lineSerie2.Points.Add(new DataPoint(5, 75));

            PM.Series.Add(lineSerie2);
            PM.Series.Add(lineSerie);

            PlotView.Model = PM;
```